# SCCM 2012: Is it possible to create an alert for when a site or component logs a critical message?

Tags: alerting, sccm-2012

I'm investigating some issues on my SCCM2012 single site installation, and am heavily relying on the 'site status' and 'component status' to tell me what's wrong. I've configured the site server to be able to send emails, and would like to be able to receive an email every time a site or component goes 'critical'.

However, I can't find anywhere that I can configure this. In 'Alerts', there's some built-in alerts, but nowhere I can create. In 'site systems', I can see an 'Alerts' tab in properties, but this is just for disk space. I've configured the SMTP settings properly, and a test email gets through.

How do I get it to email me when there's a site or component problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to this one: Install SCCM 2012 SP1.

According to Microsoft, the only email alerts configurable in SP0 are Endpoint protection alerts. With SP1, you can now generate alert emails for all configured alerts.